# Samba "access based share enum" hides all shares from browsing

Tags: linux, security, permissions, network-shares, samba

My basic `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

        access based share enum = yes

[staff]
        path = /home/shares/share-staff
        comment = test
        valid users = admin staff
        browseable = Yes
        read only = No
        directory mask = 0775
        create mask = 0644
        hide unreadable = yes

[admin]
        path = /home/shares/share-admin
        comment = test
        valid users = admin
        browseable = Yes
        read only = No
        directory mask = 0775
        create mask = 0644
        hide unreadable = yes
```

Directories `/home/shares` looks like this:

```
drwxrwx---  4 shares admin   share-admin
drwxrwx---  4 shares staff   share-staff
```

The `/home/shares` directory perms are `drwxrwxrwx` (777)

`staff` user is in the `staff` group

`admin` user is both the `admin` and `staff` group

What I expected to happen is to only see to the shares to which I have access, based on the user authenticated.  But, when I load `\\machine-name` in an explorer window on a client machine, no shares are displayed for any users.

What's wrong with my samba setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it: turns out [it's a bug](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15265).

[Temporary workaround](https://serverfault.com/a/1120302) posted by [Jeff Snider](https://serverfault.com/users/23108/jeff-snider): `chmod 666 /var/lib/samba/share_info.tdb` and restart the smb daemon.

Then it works exactly as expected by enumerating shares according to the authorized user's access.